# How can you restrict a Marketplace extension to selected projects

Tags: azure-devops

I work in a large organisation which has many VSTS online projects.

We want to create a custom VSTS online extension and only enable it for selected projects.

I would like to create a Hub extension to make use of the full screen.

The only way I can think of is by creating it as a Dashboard Widget, but this restricts me to a small ui.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn’t the feature to restrict projects for VSTS extension. I submit a user voice here: [VSTS extension project restrict](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services/suggestions/19331524-vsts-extension-project-restrict).

The workaround is that you can get current team project by using [VSS.getWebContext().](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/reference/client/core-sdk#method_getWebContext)project, then just display content for corresponding projects. (Note: Can’t set projects dynamically)